# Installation of Icecast2 beta & dev versions on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04, beta, icecast

I have been having re-occurring issues with BUTT not being able to reconnect to my icecast2 2.4.0 server using SSL after a connection loss.

I contacted the developer of BUTT and he said that is because my icecast version sometimes will not drop the dead connection. He told me to get the 2.40-KH or the 2.50-beta.3 versions where this issue has been resolved.

Now this may sound quite silly, but I don't know how to install these versions on my Ubuntu 16.04 box because the installation instruction ...

./configure
make
make install

... will not do anything.

When updating the repository Ubuntu will only get me the 2.4.4 version of icecast2.

How do I install these newer version (without messing up my config that uses URL authentification which took me months to setup)?

Glad for any help or link to detailed install instructions. And please do not tell me to upgrade my Ubuntu. This is a Webradio setup with so much special add-ins that upgrading to 20.03 would just destroy too much.

Kind regards
Paul